# Magento API v2 and C# - set custom attributes whilst adding product

Tags: c#, api, magento, soap

I have added custom attribute with the code "my_price" with "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" set to "Price" and assigned it to the "Default" (only) attribute set.

Now, I want to set its value, everytime I add/update product with API v2 (C#). Here is the code which does not work (the value is not being set):

```
// Connect & Auth:
Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient handler = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();
session_id = handler.login(username, api_key);

// Getting attributes set:
catalogProductAttributeSetEntity[] attributeSets;
attributeSets = handler.catalogProductAttributeSetList(session_id);
attributeSet = attributeSets[0];
string attributeset_id = attributeSet.set_id.ToString();

// Adding product:
catalogProductCreateEntity mageProduct = new catalogProductCreateEntity();
// (...) setting product's name, sku, etc.
associativeEntity AdditionalAttributes = new associativeEntity();
AdditionalAttributes.key = "my_price";
AdditionalAttributes.value = "12,33";
associativeEntity[] AssociativeEntity = new associativeEntity[1];
AssociativeEntity[0] = AdditionalAttributes;
mageProduct.additional_attributes = AssociativeEntity;
handler.catalogProductCreate(session_id, "simple", attributeset_id, sku, mageProduct, "default");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how about myPrice instead of my_price? Did you tried?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you figure it out. My catalogProductCrateEntity never passes any data,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento 1.6.1.0 has a bug which results with additional attributes error.

I have upgraded my Magento to 1.6.2.0 and the problem disappeared and additional attributes works perfectly.

Quick example of how it works:

```
associativeEntity[] AdditionalAttributes = new associativeEntity[1];
associativeEntity AdditionalAttribute = new associativeEntity();
AdditionalAttribute.key = "myprice";
AdditionalAttribute.value = getOriginalPrice(prices).ToString();
AdditionalAttributes[0] = AdditionalAttribute;
catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity AdditionalAttributesEntity = new catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity();
AdditionalAttributesEntity.single_data = AdditionalAttributes;

mageProduct.additional_attributes = AdditionalAttributesEntity;
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know the result.

```
AdditionalAttributes.key = "myPrice";
```

Comment: Still nothing... Do I have to refresh the service reference maybe? I really wouldn't like to do that, because there is some kind of bug and Visual Studio doesn't generate required code properly.

Comment: @Spyro I would give you a link which is old but I am definitely sure can you help to get and set product attributes. [.net C# API to Magento via XML-RPC](http://www.molotovbliss.com/net-c-api-to-magento-via-xml-rpc)

Comment: this is other link [.NET C# Object Library for Magento's XML-RPC API](http://code.google.com/p/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi/)

Answer (score 0):

```
handler.catalogProductCreate(session_id, "simple", attributeset_id, sku, mageProduct, "default");
```

Give valid storeview instead of **default** e.g. try this:

```
handler.catalogProductCreate(session_id, "simple", attributeset_id, sku, mageProduct, "1");
```